# Laravel 4 permissions

Tags: php, authentication, permissions, laravel, laravel-4

so this is basically the sql model i got so far:

[image]

This is, how it would look at my users controller (stackoverflow formatting):

```
if (Auth::user()->is('admin'))
                    {
                            if (Auth::user()->can('delete'))
                            {
                                    echo 'hurra!';
                            }
                    }
```

Permission keys will probably look like this

> admin.delete
>   maybe something like user.can.buy

And now i want to know if it's alright, how i perform it in the methods:

```
public function is($roleName)
        {
                $role = $this->roles;

                if ($role->name == $roleName)
                {
                        return true;
                }

                return false;
        }
```

I think this one's good

BUT

```
public function can($permissionKey)
        {
                $permissions = $this->roles->permissions()
                        ->where('key', $permissionKey)
                        ->count();

                if ($permissions > 0)
                {
                        return true;
                }

                return false;
        }
```

looks kinda awkward to me. Is this the right way i am selecting data with eloquent orm?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: All Looks fine to me. I've made a similar bundle at http://github.com/Toddish/Verify if you want to compare code.

Comment: thank you for the hint. definately going to check your ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well i lnstalled a profiler and checked all triggered sql queries:

select * from `users` where `id` = '1' limit 1

select * from `roles` where `id` = '1' limit 1

select count(*) as aggregate from `permissions` inner join `permission_role` on `permissions`.`id` = `permission_role`.`permission_id` where `permission_role`.`role_id` = '1' and `key` = 'view.admin'

this looks alright to me, so i think the way i did it, is ok.